# qq.FileUpload: Get the true id when using multiple qq.FileUpload and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload

I'm using this fileupload [plug-in](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Here is my code (compressed)

```
    var uploader1 = new qq.FileUploader({
        *some options*,
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (!responseJSON.success) {
                alert(responseJSON.message);
                return;
            }
            alert(id);
        }
    });

    var uploader2 = new qq.FileUploader({
        *some options*,
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (!responseJSON.success) {
                alert(responseJSON.message);
                return;
            }
            alert(id);
        }
    });
```

I have to do many stuff depending of the id.
The problem is:

With Google Chrome:

1. Add file with uploader1
2. Alert(id) = 0
3. Add file with uploader2
4. Alert(id) = 0
5. Add second file with uploader2
6. Alert(id) = 1

With Internet Explorer:

1. Add file with uploader1
2. Alert(id) = qq-upload-handler-iframe0
3. Add file with uploader2
4. Alert(id) = qq-upload-handler-iframe1
5. Add second file with uploader2
6. Alert(id) = qq-upload-handler-iframe2

Any idea? How I can get the unique id like Chrome in Internet Explorer? I don't find any documentation about methods on qqFileUpload